# Mypy: How to create an alias type with all classes from a module

Tags: python-3.x, types, mypy

I have a module `foo`that defines a lot of classes, e.g.

```
class A():
  ...
class B():
 ...
class C():
 ...
...
```

I would like to create a "foo type" alias comprising all these classes, i.e.

`my_foo_type = Union[A, B, C, ...]`

Yet, there are so many classes that I don't want to type them but have programmatic solution. I access to all classes defined in the module via

```
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(foo):
    if inspect.isclass(obj):
        print(obj)
```

How can I connect this with the type alias?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I don't know what you want to do with your classes; depending on your use case, you could: 1. make your classes subclasses of a base class; 2. use an external script that will generate the type variable for you (and run this script each time you add/remove a class in your module); 3. something else `:)`.

Comment: The base class is a good idea. I will accept that as an answer if you transform your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. I don't know what you want to do with your classes but depending on your use case, you could:

1. make your classes subclasses of a base class (it may also improve the design of your module);
2. use an external script that will generate the type variable for you (and run this script each time you add or remove a class in your module);
3. something else :)